# Access to Oracle DB deployed inside Parallels Desktop from Mac OS

Tags: oracle, macos, database-connection, parallels

I have Mac OS Big Sur 11.6.5 and installed Windows 10 inside Parallels Desktop 17. In Windows i configured oracle server and all working as i want, but i have a problem - i want to have access to oracle database from mac os but i can't do it, because:

I checked ipconfig in windows:
[image: ipconfig details]

I see that ip address of my windows machine is 10.211.55.5

In Mac os i tried to connect to oracle database like:

[image: oracle db connection conf]

The similar config for db connection working inside windows, just instead 10.211.55.5 i used localhost. But in mac os i see long time connection and error in the end:

[image: connection error]

After it i tried to ping 10.211.55.5 from mac os and saw:

[image: ping cmd results]

Seems that my mac os see windows machine and can successfully ping it.

What i do wrong? How to setup connection with Oracle DB inside my VM?

Answer (score 1):

After sometime i found the solution, need to open port 1521 in windows machine, i used instruction from here:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-open-port-in-windows-10-firewall/f38f67c8-23e8-459d-9552-c1b94cca579a